# FM Radio Content Filtering, Preprocessing on Android

Tags: android

I would like to replicate the FM radio on Android with an added feature, if there are certain types of sounds (ads, talk) I want to skip to the next station. I need to be able to access the byte stream coming from the FM radio, and was wondering what APIs or additional libraries I need to do this. I know Java and coded Android applications before.

Note: This is specifically about the FM radio, as in radio waves, not Internet radio.

Thanks,

Comment: There is nothing in the Android SDK related to FM radio support.

Comment: So it's all on the chip and there is only one call that says "play station"?

Comment: I have no idea what the manufacturer's FM radio app does and how it interfaces with whatever FM radio support might be offered by the manufacturer's chosen chipset.